# Hash code is different for TransformBlock and ComputeHash method in HMAC-SHA1

Tags: .net, encryption, hmacsha1

When I use TransformBlock and TransformFinalBlock for a buffer the hash code is different from Computing hashcode with ComputeHash() method in HMAC-SHA1 . why? And how to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a problem with your code, then you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem. Help us help you without wasting time on guessing. Also, don't provide a link to your code. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code. Links break all the time and if it does, this question will lose all value.

Comment: You already asked the same question before (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588030/how-to-implement-transformblock-and-transformfinalblock-in-hmacsha1-for-uwp#comment76170309_44588030). Please be more specific what you are asking and what you are trying to do. I would again recommend using a solid hardened crypto implementations available.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't offer any code it's not possible to say for sure, but psychic debugging says that you assumed `TransformFinalBlock` returned the HMAC, which it just computes a value into the `Hash` property.

```
byte[] data = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55 };
HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
Console.WriteLine($"ComputeHash: {Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(data))}");
Console.WriteLine($"TransformFinalBlock: {Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length))}");
Console.WriteLine($"get_Hash: {Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.Hash)}");
```

Outputs

```
ComputeHash: 3J86gFtyUDTwqyZdY8dgBPAyL6Q=
TransformFinalBlock: AQECAwUIDRUiNw==
get_Hash: 3J86gFtyUDTwqyZdY8dgBPAyL6Q=
```

So, the answer is to ignore the result of TransformFinalBlock (which echoes the input), and to call get_Hash afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(v=vs.110).aspx) HMACSHA1 **mixes secret key with input message** in order to produce final hash, that is mixed and hashed again...

If you won't provide secret key, it'll be randomly generated that will result in **different** hash.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

[TestClass]
public class HashTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void HashTest()
    {
        var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("my secret key");
        var textBytes = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes("my tiny little text");

        var hash1 = GetHash1(textBytes, keyBytes);
        var hash2 = GetHash2(textBytes, keyBytes);

        Assert.AreEqual(hash1.Length, hash2.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < hash1.Length; i++)
            Assert.AreEqual(hash1[i], hash2[i]);
    }

    private byte[] GetHash2(byte[] textBytes, byte[] key)
    {
        using (var alg = new HMACSHA1(key))
            return alg.ComputeHash(textBytes);
    }

    private byte[] GetHash1(byte[] input, byte[] key)
    {
        var size = input.Length;
        using (var alg = new HMACSHA1(key))
        {
            int offset = 0;

            while (input.Length - offset >= size)
                offset += alg.TransformBlock(input, offset, size, input, offset);

            alg.TransformFinalBlock(input, offset, size - offset);
            return alg.Hash;
        }
    }
}
```